# ¿Ha usado el castellano siempre la tilde para romper diptongos?

Tags: ortografía, historia, acentuación, diptongos

En catalán le llamamos *llaüt* al ***laúd*** español. En ambos casos la pronunciación es parecida, con un diptongo que se rompe con un signo gráfico.

Lo que me parece curioso del caso es que lo que en el castellano se opta por utilizar una tilde para romper ese diptongo. Teniendo en cuenta las reglas de ortografía, una palabra aguda terminada en `d` no debe llevar tilde, pero se usa para romper el diptongo.

En catalán, por contra, esa rotura se efectúa utilizando la diéresis.

En castellano solamente usamos la diéresis con la `u` y para darle sonoridad cuando no debería tenerla: `ambigüedad`, `cigüeña`, `lingüística`.

Así que me pregunto: ¿siempre se usó la tilde para romper diptongos? ¿Se utilizó en el pasado la diéresis o algún otro signo gráfico con esta función?

Comment: La diéresis se usa con gran frecuencia en la poesía cuando es preciso romper un diptongo por razones métricas sin modificar la sílaba tónica.  Por ejemplo, la palabra *diferencia*, si fuese necesario enfatizar una pronunciación de cinco sílabas /di.fe'ren.θi.a/ en vez de las cuatro normales /di.fe'ren.θja/, se escribiría *diferencïa*. Tal vez la palabra que más frecuentemente veo así es *suave*, que parece que los poetas tienden a preferir en tres sílabas /su'a.be/ y no las dos normales /'swa.be/. Pero dudo que haya habido otra forma, el uso sistemático de la tilde es más moderno que antiguo.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Es difícil dar una respuesta orientada al "no", pero allá voy. He buscado en el CORDE ocurrencias en textos del siglo XV de palabras que contengan la *ï*. Casi todo lo que he encontrado son ocurrencias en textos de poesía. Ninguna ocurrencia en algún texto en prosa que pueda inducir a pensar que en tiempos se usara la diéresis. Lo mismo para el grupo *aü* y otros, todos en poesía.

Luego busqué particularmente "laúd", "laud" y "laüd" en textos hasta 1600, con las siguientes ocurrencias:

- Laúd: 114 ocurrencias en 45 documentos.
- Laud: 52 ocurrencias en 27 documentos.
- Laüd: 1 ocurrencia en 1 documento.

Esta ocurrencia de "laüd" es la siguiente:

> *Los bienes que fueron secrestados por de Lope Caluca y su hermano, Sevastián, vezinos de Pataura, que se pasaron aliende en XXVI de abril de MDLXIII años. Los quales fueron secrestados por Juan Gonçalez Castrejón, capitán de Motril, son los siguientes. Ante Hernán Rruiz escrivano público de Motril. Bienes muebles de los dichos Lope Caluca y Sevastián Caluca: Un colchón de tascos, viejo. Dos almohadas de lienço, llenas de atocha. Una arquilla, pequeña, vazía. Un arca grande, vieja, vazía. Un sayo azul, viejo. Una estera de junco, vieja. Una sábana de lienço. Otro colchón viejo. Una colcha vieja. Un **laüd** morisco, viejo, quebrado. Dos puertas de madera. Los quales dichos bienes se depositaron en poder de Hernando Azara, vezino de la villa de Motril e los rreçibió e se obligó en forma ante el dicho Hernán Rruiz, escrivano.*
>
> Anónimo, "Inventario de bienes [Inventarios de bienes moriscos del Reino de Granada]", España (1563).

Era un documento notarial, así que de poesía poca. Ignoro por qué escribió "laüd" con diéresis.

Por otro lado, buscando textos que contengan la propia palabra "diptongo" a una distancia cercana de palabras como "acento" o "tilde", me encuentro con este:

> *Si compusiéramos verso i quisiéramos que la palabra Dios, que sólo tiene una sílaba, se desatase en dos por la diéresis, escriviríamos assí, Dïòs. Los dos puntos entonces denotarían la división del diftongo, i el acento sobrepuesto a la ò que la final es larga a diferencia del pretérito díos, cuya i es aguda, i la final, breve.*
>
> Gregorio Mayans y Siscar, "Abecé español", España (c 1723)

Vuelta a las referencias a la poesía, pero nada al respecto de la prosa.

Comment: Interesante investigación, Carlos. Por tanto, podemos descartar el uso de la diéresis para tal fin. Quizá en el futuro nos encontremos un texto con algún símbolo distinto para romper diptongos, pero como no es el caso asumo que simplemente siempre se usó lo que ahora: la tilde.